# ODP Oracle managed Client - ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: .net, oracle

I know this issue was already been reported, but after searching for 2 days I've found nothing useful to solve the problem.

I was trying to connect to ORACLE (version 9) with ODP Managed oracle client version 18 (added trough nuget package manager), I've just created a simple .net (framework 4) console application that opens a connection and execute a select.

The connection.open() fails with the error "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

Both user and pwd are correct, I've tested them in Sql developer.
I've found some soultions that did not helped, such double quoting the user and password in connection string.

some others said to set the registry value of
System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled to 0

But when i checked mine it was already 0

Or alternatively add

```html
<runtime>
    <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

in app.config

Some others said to disable case sensitive password in oracle but the password is already case insensitive, I've tried it in sql developer and I can access with lowercase or uppercase password without issues.

I'm a bit lost, I don't understand the issue and it seems I can't find a solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to an Oracle 9 database with *Oracle Data Provider for .NET*.

See [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT149)

> **System Requirements**
>
> - Access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 or later

Either upgrade your database to current release (Oracle 9 is almost 20 years old) or use and old ODP.NET Unmanaged Driver. The oldest version you can download from Oracle page is version 11.2. According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT148) you can still connect to Oracle 9i Release 2.

Comment: Thanks both, unfortunately I cannot upgrade the database since it is from another supplier, I've switched to unmanaged driver with odbc